# W5500 2-layer PCB or 4 layers?

Tags: ethernet, pcb-layers

I am in process of hiring a freelancer to develop a PCB which will incorporate Wiznet W5500 ethernet IC.
Some have suggested a 4 layer PCB, but some are saying it is possible in 2 layers.
As the board has many buffer IC's and other connectors which don't require 4 layers.
I am skeptical to take this decision and need help.

Please advice. Thanks!

Comment: If you are hiring a PCB freelancer, do you not trust their decision on how many layers *they* believe are necessary for a clean design with suitable signal integrity?

Comment: 50 % have the opposite opinion sadly

Comment: Have you asked them to briefly justify their decision? It's perfectly possible that our community here will also be split on two and four layers, depending on our individual experiences and preferred practices.

Comment: I will definitely go with 2 layers if anyone has had success with it. Unfortunately no one has developed a PCB with that chip among the freelancers I am communicating with

Comment: 4 layers will be easier to get right first time, and may well be smaller. 2 layers will be cheaper once working. The pinout looks pretty tame, and should not preclude 2 layers.

Comment: Thank you for your advice Neil_UK

Comment: Not done myself but this Eagle CAD is a 2 layer board.  http://wizwiki.net/wiki/doku.php?id=osh:ioshield-a:start

Comment: 4 layers in all probability will be a quieter board, with proper ground/power planes. This can improve reliability and lead to a working product faster. Consider how many you are making : volume has to be pretty high to justify spending more time getting the 2 layer design working right if you aren't lucky first time.

Comment: In 2020, the cost difference for a 4-layer board is 100% worth it to allow for a solid ground plane (yielding much better EMI/EMC properties), unless you plan to make tens of thousands of these things, and even then, it might not be justified, imho. I mean not _everything_ needs to be 4-layers, but when I have any doubts these days, I can usually justify it to myself.

Comment: The cost difference is 100% worth it maybe if PCB's are sourced from China. India still doesn't have good manufacturers for 4 layer PCBs. And the good ones are very expensive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to make a board smaller in 4-layer so the square inches may compensate somewhat. 4 layer has dropped quite a bit in price in the last couple years, price starts to tick up considerably at 6 or more.

That said, 2 layer looks do-able. There [was a layout](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/367483/is-my-pcb-layout-ok-atmega32u4-wiznet-w5500-ethernet) here some time ago which has a number of examples of what not to do (pours are not great, power lines don't look great, crystals are very poorly and unnecessarily placed in relation to other lines). Make sure that the freelancer follows the [hardware guide](https://wizwiki.net/wiki/doku.php/design_guide:hardware:start).

Personally, I would go for 4-layer unless I had a lot of confidence in the designer and budgeted enough of their time to take care with signal and power integrity (assuming they know how to do that in the first place). On the other hand, a novice following the guide would likely not have any issues with a reasonable 4-layer or more layout. I've seen some pretty slapdash subcontractors purveying their work online.

Comment: Thank you for your help!